# Get ordered field names from peewee Model

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'd like to use peewee to [create](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.create) records from a csv. It looks like the syntax requires keyword args:

```
user = User.create(username='admin', password='test')
```

If the rows in the csv look like `(admin, test)`, it would be convenient to know the field names `('username', 'password')` to form a dict to pass in (it looks like I can't pass in a list of the values for the model to infer what the corresponding fields are).

Is there a property of `User` that has a list of the field names in the order that they are defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like it's `User._meta.get_field_names()`

I just saw someone else mention it in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864940/python-dumping-database-data-with-peewee).

Comment: Note to self: don't use `User` as a model name

Comment: I just stumbled on this question: Why wouldn't you use User as a model name?

Comment: It's a [reserved word in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891368/postgres-table-column-name-restrictions). Peewee handles it fine, but it makes it trickier to use the console.

Comment: Update for those that stumble onto this question: For newer versions of peewee, you need to use `User._meta.sorted_fields` or `User._meta.sorted_field_names`

Comment: I had to use `<class>._meta.fields.keys()` because `sorted_field_names` wasn't returning Foreign Keys (sometimes).

Comment: @kev -- that's not correct. Were you expecting it to return back-references or something?

Comment: @Ian thank, couldn't find in in peewee document. how did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is for an older version of Peewee. The proper way to do this is either:

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    ...

sorted_field_names = SomeModel._meta.sorted_field_names
```

Answer (score -1):

The given approved answer did not work for me, but the below code did.

```py
YourModel._meta.columns.keys()
```